# Do MSI variants of RTX 3060Ti have especially bad temperatures

Tags: graphics-card, cooling, temperature

I recently bought an MSI RTX 3060Ti, it has 2 month warranty left. I am not sure how much is it used. I use 2K monitor 144Hz display.

Max temperature on FurMark is 76 and when playing games, the temperature is between 77 and 79. Is it bad? Is it due to MSI being a variant having high temperatures? Should I apply new thermal paste and pads? I really doubt that the card needs thermal paste, since I don't think the card is too old.

I know most people say the temperatures are fine for GPU, but there are variants out there which have max temperature of 68.

Answer (score 1):

The
[MSI GeForce RTX 3060 Ti GAMING X TRIO Video Card Review](https://www.thefpsreview.com/2020/12/16/msi-geforce-rtx-3060-ti-gaming-x-trio-video-card-review/7/)
shows that temperatures at the 70-80 degrees are normal for this
very powerful family of cards:

[image]